# Select Title Element with certain criteria XMLPath

Tags: xml, xpath

Given an XML structure like so:

```
<CATALOG>
  <Computer ID="1">
    <TITLE>Deep Blue</TITLE>
    <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>No</COMPANY>
  </Computer>
  <Computer ID="2">
    <TITLE>Linux</TITLE>
    <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
    <AVAILABILITY>Yes</AVAILABILITY>
  </Computer>
</CATALOG>
```

I want to get the TITLE Element of the Computer which is from the COUNTRY USA.
With */[text() = 'USA'] i get all Elements which contain the USA Text but not the TITLE.
Thanks for your help

Edit: The sample above is just a small snippet of the whole code

Comment: not sure if i got it right but could it be :
CATALOG/Computer[COUNTRY/ text() = 'USA']/TITLE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your XPath expression.

> XPath

```
/CATALOG/Computer[COUNTRY='USA']/TITLE
```